# Machine Learning book for fundamentals - Simon Haykin vs. Christopher M. Bishop

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, books

Since I started studying Machine Learning, I was torn between two books in this area, and I could never decide which one is the best to follow.

The first book is widely used and known: Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, by Christopher Bishop. I've never head about him before, probably because he is a Computer Scientist and I am an Engineer, and he doesn't have many books, AFAIK. But I know that this one I like a bible for machine learning fundamentals.

However, I came across another book: Neural Networks and Learning Machine, by Simon Haykin. I am very familiar with this author since I already read many of his books throughout my graduation on other topics, such as communication systems, signals and systems, adaptive filters, etc... Then I decided to read it and I like it a lot!

However, I realized that Bishop is much more referenced than Simon Haykin regarding machine learning. Furthermore, both books differ a lot with regard to terms. For instance, the term "induced local field", which is largely adopted in the Simon Haykin's book, is not even mentioned once by Bishop (at least, I didn't find it when I looked it up).

All of these aspects make me fell unconformable and doubtful about my book adoption since I could use expressions and terms that I not so used by other authors.

It may be a taste matter, but I do need suggestions whether the Bishop's book is much better than anything else to get the foundations or it is ok to adopt Simon Haykin.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the Haykin's book.

The Bishop book seem to be the standard text for a graduate-level course in CS departments in top research universities.

I remember back in the day when I took the ML course, the professor used the Bishop book and was very fond of it.

He said he had read the book three times, once as a undergrad, once as a PhD student, and once when he taught from the book as a professor. And he said after three reads, he finally got every detail in the book.

Basically, he was saying the book was quite dense and written in a way that is not easily penetrable, but once you truly get it, you would appreciate the beauty of exposition style of the book.